# Conversion to non-scalar error inside macro in C

Tags: c, malloc

I have the following test code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct test {
    int a;
    int b;
} test_t;

#define test_init(test, a)                      \
    test = (test_t)calloc(1, sizeof(test_t));   \
    (test)->a = a;                              \
    (test)->b = (test)->a + 1;                  \

int main()
{
    test_t test;
    int a = 5;
    test_init(&test, a);

    return 0;
}
```

But it throws the following error:

```
error: conversion to non-scalar type requested
```

Why exactly dos this happen? Please note that the discussion is not here whether to use an actual function or a macro. Let's just assume we are interested in macros. Why is the above error thrown, and what is the proper way to handle it?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/zut3W6

Comment: If you're going to create macros like this, I'd suggest putting them in a `do{...}while(0)` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that function-like macros perform a direct substitution of their parameters.  That means this:

```
test_init(&test, a);
```

Gets converted by the preprocessor into:

```
&test = (test_t)calloc(1, sizeof(test_t));
(&test)->a = a;
(&test)->b = (&test)->a + 1;
```

Note that in the first line you're attempting to assign something to `&test`.  The result of the `&` operator does not result in an lvalue.  That means you can't assign something to `&test` because it doesn't represent something you can assign to.

To fix this, you need to declare `test` in main as a pointer:

```
test_t *test;
int a = 5;
test_init(test, a);
```

Or, if you expect the macro to be passed an instance of type `test_t`, you don't need the call to `calloc`:

```
#define test_init(test, a)                \
(test).a = a;                             \
(test).b = (test).a + 1;                  \
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.